# How to integrate Firebase Auth with PHP app?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a simple PHP API which is used to authenticate users that use my app.
I have been trying to use Firebase Auth, without any success.
Following the documentation found [here](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I came to a point where:

- I have created the Firebase project in the Firebase console.
- I have created a Service Account, for which I have downloaded the Secret .json file that contains the credentials needed.
- I have placed the file in the root directory of my app.

And I use this code to interact with the database:

```
    $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/path/to/file.json');

    $firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
        ->createAuth();
```

When dumping the $firebase instance I get this:

```
^ Kreait\Firebase\Auth {#78 ▼
  -client: Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient {#55 ▶}
  -tokenGenerator: Firebase\Auth\Token\Generator {#58 ▶}
  -idTokenVerifier: Kreait\Firebase\Auth\IdTokenVerifier {#77 ▶}
}
```

Which makes me believe the connection is successful, but when I try to list all the users

```
    $firebase->listUsers();
```

I get the following

```
^ Generator {#42 ▼
   this: Kreait\Firebase\Auth {#78 …}
   executing: {▼
     C:\Users\user\Projects\Simple-Api\vendor\kreait\firebase- 
php\src\Firebase\Auth.php:110 {▼
       Kreait\Firebase\Auth->listUsers(int $maxResults = 1000, int $batchSize = 1000): Generator …
       › {
       ›     $pageToken = null;
       ›     $count = 0;
     }
   }
   closed: false
 }
```

And when I try to loop through all the users like this:

```
   foreach ($users as $user) {
         var_dump($user);
     }
```

I get these error:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate prblm: unable to get local issuer certificate
cURL error 77: SSL certificate prblm: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

**TEMPORARY FIX (not suggested for production):**

- Go to Guzzle Client.php class
- Set verify to false

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to follow the documentation, you will find

https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-management.html#list-users

`Auth::listUsers()` returns a Generator, which you can either loop through with `foreach()` or convert to an array with `iterator_to_array()` - you should use the latter only if you limit the resultset, otherwise you will run into performance issues when PHP tries to load thousands of user records into memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jeromegamez , I have already tried what you suggested and I get this error: ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify location```. Do you reckon that the .json file is not the one it should be ?

Comment: @Pmits Uh, that's one I haven't heard about yet... Could you have a look at https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#curl-error-xx and see if this helps resolve the issue? Your JSON file is probably fine, this seem to be a connection issue 

Comment: I think that's the appropriate solution, thank you. I have also updated the question with a quick fix that I made only for testing purposes though. Thanks again.